# Org-mode note and Evil - go into insert mode and change shortcuts

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evil-mode

I'm using Emacs with Org-mode and evil-mode.
When inserting a note (`:org-add-note`) I would like to start in insert mode, as well as change the shortcuts (from `C-c C-c` to `RET`, and `C-c C-k` to `C-g`).

While I know of `org-capture-mode-hook`, it doesn't seem to work for the org-add-note command.

Any ideas?